# are SerializableWrappers for collections a bad idea?

Tags: java, serialization, collections

There are plenty of collections that are not `Serializable`. Some particularly annoying ones are the `keySet` and `values` collections on a `HashMap` (see JDK bugs [4756277](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4756277) and [4501848](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4501848) for that discussion).

If I need to serialize one of these collections, one suggested workaround is to whack the contents in another collection that does implement `Serializable` and send that instead. For example:

```
Set<T> realSet = myHashMap.keySet();
Set<T> toSerialize = new HashSet<T>(realSet);
```

I don't like the overhead of this, especially when considering that the implementation of the serialization operation is typically as simple as writing out the size and iterating *once* through the set.

This leads me to the idea of a serializable wrapper class that implements this simple serialization form and has only a transient reference to the delegate, in the spirit of `synchronizedSet` and friends. Something like this, with the implementation depending only on `size()` and `iterator`, and deserializing with `readResolve` to give a `HashSet`, say.

This feels slightly dirty. Where are the real holes?

- fails to handle collections based on an equivalence relation to that of `HashSet` (`TreeSet`, `IdentityHashMap` etc.). I can't see that this matters too much, we just don't specify results on these types of collections, as is seen elsewhere.
- are there serialization gotchas about version uid that will prevent this from working? About to try it...
- this would not respect the specification of, say, a `HashMap#keySet()` when deserialized, in that it would not be a live view of the mappings. Is it ok just to specify that it's a static view of the mappings at the time at which it was serialized?

Comment: The real problem comes when you have to serialize both a reference to the Map and to keySet. Copying the keySet will obviously not keep both collections synchronized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't like the overhead of this

Premature optimization. With 99% certainty, using the copy constructor will not be the performance bottleneck in your program. You should not even begin this kind of consideration until a profiler tells you what is.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation I went with 
http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/  
It is very simple to implement and has a few immediate benefits. The idea is that instead of serializing the object directly each object wraps a message, all a message is is a set of variables and their values. Then you serialize the message. To reinstate the object you just pass the message to a constructor and set its state. 
protobuf decouples serialization from re-serialization(erm and the language you serialized the data in)

On another note Java serialization in terms of data size is absurd. Java encodes the objects package name so if you use namespaces like you should in Java com.thisismyobject.manthesecharactersareaddingup is embedded in every transmission for every serialized objects so say you had nested objects in the serialized objects is will be almost 20 times the size of the actual useful data!

Comment: That's not a bad idea at all, though would entail the work of switching to protobuf on all the client objects. Unfortunately my motivating case is using RMI, so I really do need normal serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution will be to implement some methods for serialization/deserialization of such collections by yourself. So you will be independ from java collections framework's changes.

Comment: Indeed. The question is more whether the wrapper is a sensible idea, or whether we should stick with copying the contents into another collection before serializing. I think we can assume that the serialized form of `HashSet` is not going to change in the near future...